# How do I specify a non-system python instllation for setup tools installtion?

Tags: python-3.3

I'm trying to setup Kivy with python 3.X in which python3.3.0 is compiled/installed into the opt directory, and a Kivy virtualenv is setup and working in my home directory. I followed the Kivy documentation under section titled “Ubuntu 12.04 with Python 3.3” and also tried to modify this script https://gist.github.com/brousch/8426921. The problem I'm having is both Kivy documentation and the script posted on Github assumes the user installed Python 3 using ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes. The line below does not work and I cant seem to figure out how to force the last part (i.e. sudo python3.3) point to a python installation of my choosing. I did read the setuptools docs but it's not clear as it provides no examples. This is for Linux Mint 13 64-bit.

How do I replace “| sudo python3.3” in the line below to specify a non-system python install?

```
# Bootstrap current setuptools
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The '| sudo python3.3' command executes the .py with python3.3 installed at

```
/usr/bin/python3.3
```

So, to change it, you just have to change the path. Do so like this.

```
| sudo /path/to/python
```